# Detecting known words using the Web Speech API

Tags: web, speech-recognition

I'm in the planning stages of a web app that is intended to help children learn vocabulary. We would like to make the app as interactive as possible. For example, we would show a picture of an apple and ask the child to identify the object. The child would then say "apple" and we would determine whether they are correct, etc.

The new [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechreco-result) seems like a promising tool for this project. However, looking through the documentation, I believe it will only produce transcripts from speech (i.e. it cannot match a spoken word to a *known* word and produce a confidence value – at least not out of the box).

Does anyone have experience with leveraging the Web Speech API in this way (or any other API for that matter)? I'm trying to stick to technologies that can run in the browser, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ispikit.com](http://www.ispikit.com/), it's way more suitable for your needs, it's specifically designed for education tasks and works in a browser on a client side. Web Speech API is not designed for detection, so you will not be able to use it.